# update map marker of friends continuously without reloading UI android

Tags: java, android

My map has markers of friends. I want to update marker of them whenever they move. I have done this by reloading "UI" by timer task which may irritate user.
But i want to update marker without reloading "UI" i mean which will not visible to user.

I am new in android so please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make two list one contain Markers and another containing MarkerOptions as below :

```
ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markerOptionList = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And when you get the updated list of latitude and longitude then call the method below :

```
 public  void  setMarker(GoogleMap map, ArrayList<Double> latitudeList, ArrayList<Double> longitudeList, ArrayList<String> titleList){
        mMap = map;
        for(int j=0;j<markerList.size();j++){
            markerList.get(j).remove();
        }
        markerList.clear();
        markerOptionList.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<latitudeList.size();i++){
            LatLng position = new LatLng(latitudeList.get(i), longitudeList.get(i));

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                    .title("" + titleList.get(i))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

            markerOptionList.add(options);
            Marker marker =  mMap.addMarker(markerOptionList.get(i));
            markerList.add(marker);
        }

    }
```

This will update the markers on the map only instead of loading whole map again which may irritates the user.